# Where is the source code for the layoutopt tool in the Android SDK?

Tags: android, android-sdk-tools

The *layoutopt.exe* in the SDK/tools folder for Android.

Where can I find the rules it works with etc?

The source code location would help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **[source.android.com](http://source.android.com)** website is a good place to start.

There is a section for the SDK - https://android.googlesource.com/platform/sdk

And you can then drill down into the **layoutopt** folder:

- [platform/sdk/layoutopt](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/sdk/+/tools_r12/layoutopt) in sdk repo

Answer (score 1):

I found that Apache Groovy framework is used to implement rule engine. there are 11 rules layoutopt implement on every layout (XML). check following link for more detail.

http://kpbird.blogspot.ru/2011/08/android-in-depth-how-layoutopt-works.html